# How do I delete sites from Safari reading list?

Tags: safari, reading-list

How do I delete sites from my Safari reading list? There is no delete button.

Answer (score 3):

1. Click on “Safari” to launch it.
2. Select the “View” menu. It is the one, which has the book icon.
3. Choose “Show Reading list Sidebar” You can also press Command + Control + 2. You will see your Reading List.
4. Select the item you wish to delete. Then right-click on it and select Remove Item.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily delete items in your reading list by following these steps:

1. click on Show Sidebar (red mark)
2. select reading list (blue glasses)
3. right click on the item -> Remove item

   [image]